# Laravel WithSum / WithCount Relationships not bringing results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to make a query using Laravel eloquent but at the moment I have not had good results.

My query is about the scope of relationships in Laravel. We have two tables:

- table 1 : `orders`
- table 2 : `products` in `orders` (depends on table 1)

We have a relationship in the model.

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class);
}
```

`OrderProduct` (detail of `products` in `orders`) has the following fields:

- `id`
- `order_id`
- `product_id`
- `qty`
- `line_total`

What we are trying to achieve is a query that returns the sum of `line_total` when the `product_id` is `139`.

We tried the following options without success in the controller:

1. ```
   $orderspaid = Order::with('products')
       ->where('customer_id', '=', Auth::id())
       ->where('status', '=', 'completed')
       ->withSum ('products','line_total')
       ->where('product_id', '=', '139')
       ->get();
   ```

   > Error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_id'
2. ```
   $orderspaid = Order::withCount(['products as orderproducts' => function($query) {
       $query->where('orderproducts.product_id', '=', 139)
             ->select(DB::raw('sum(line_total)'));
   }])->get();
   ```

   But with no success.

My main question is, it is possible to use `sum(line_total)` or `withSum('products','line_total')` to directly sum the amount of money that a particular `product_id` have?.

Additional Info: Tinker information displaying the relationship between orders and orderproducts.

[image]

Comment: since `product_id` is in the pivot table can you try with `->wherePivot('product_id', '=', '139')`?

Comment: following your advice I receive "Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause "

Comment: Why not this way? `OrderProduct::select(DB::raw('sum(qty * line_total) as total'))->where(['product_id' => 139])->first();`

Comment: @s_h Can you add model relationships and relating fields corresponding to the question? You declared that `line_total` is in the pivot table, but your attempt with `withSum` doesn't imply so. At which table exactly is `line_total` located?

Comment: Since you have a pivot table, you should define a `belongsToMany` relationship between products and orders not `hasMany`. This will instruct Laravel about your pivot table

Comment: @unclexo your code work very well for table order_products but is not making a relationship with orders. in orders we have the customer id so we can filter per each customer. if OrderProduct::select(DB::raw('sum(qty * line_total) as total'))->where(['product_id' => 139])->with('orders')->where('orders.customer_id', '=', Auth::id())->first() that would be great. But where('orders.customer_id' is not the way it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one. I don't have those tables ready to test so I could be wrong

So basicly, the method being tried is that `products` with wanted `id` will be preloaded, in this case, it's `139`. When `withSum` is called on `products` table, it will use eagerly products that have been specified beforehand.

```
$product_id = 139;
$orderspaid = Order::with(['products' => function ($query) use ($product_id) {
    $query->where(`products.id`, $product_id);
}])
    ->where('customer_id', '=', Auth::id())
    ->where('status', '=', 'completed')
    ->withSum('products', 'line_total')
    ->get();
dd($orderspaid);
```

Tell me if that works for you.